# How to connect EWS (Problematically) through windows phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have been trying since last 3 days to connect EWS from windows phone 8.1. But I'm unable to connect with EWS.

I'm following this blog..
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/78396950-7549-4f4f-92a6-bdf48c35300d/error-integrating-ews-22-with-windows-phone-81-app?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment

As per above site, the code which they did if we will implement that code in windows phone 8.1, the code give us exception "Method is not supported".

If we try to connect edmx url of EWS by using **HttpClient** from windows phone 8.1.. It will give us unauthorized ERROR.

I have checked iphone and android code for connect EWS. Its working fine.

Can any one help me for this?

```
Hi Jason,

I tried using HTTPWebRequest, in a sample command line project and it works fine. Below is the code -

public bool Request(string URL, string RequestXML, NetworkCredential UserCredentials)
        {
            HttpWebRequest SoapRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
            StreamWriter RequestWriter=null;
            Stream ResponseStream=null;
            HttpWebResponse SoapResponse=null;
            try
            {
                SoapRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
                SoapRequest.Credentials = UserCredentials;
                SoapRequest.Method = "POST";
                SoapRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";

                RequestWriter = new StreamWriter(SoapRequest.GetRequestStream());
                RequestWriter.Write(RequestXML);
                RequestWriter.Close();
                SoapResponse = (HttpWebResponse)SoapRequest.GetResponse();
                if (SoapResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    ResponseStream = SoapResponse.GetResponseStream();
                    ResponseEnvelop = XElement.Load(ResponseStream);
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ResponseEnvelop = null;
                return false;
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                SoapRequest = null;
                RequestWriter.Dispose();
                RequestWriter = null;
                ResponseStream.Dispose();
                ResponseStream = null;
                SoapResponse.Dispose();
                SoapResponse = null;
            }
        }
-------------

However some methods are not available in Windows App, so tried below code. There are no compile errors but I receive error "Method not supported". I am trying from weeks but no luck, wondering is some help is available

public async Task<bool> Request(string URL, string RequestXML, NetworkCredential UserCredentials)
        {
            HttpWebRequest SoapRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
            StreamWriter RequestWriter = null;
            Stream ResponseStream = null;
            WebResponse SoapResponse = null;
            try
            {
                SoapRequest.Credentials = UserCredentials;
                SoapRequest.Method = "POST";
                SoapRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
                RequestWriter = new StreamWriter(await System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Stream>.Run(() => SoapRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync()));
                RequestWriter.AutoFlush = true;
                RequestWriter.Write(RequestXML);
                SoapResponse = await System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Stream>.Run(() => SoapRequest.GetResponseAsync());
                ResponseStream = SoapResponse.GetResponseStream();
                ResponseEnvelop = XElement.Load(ResponseStream);
                return true;
            }

Appreciate some quick help

Thanks,

Nasir
```

Comment: Whoa. You are continuing a discussion from another forum here? That is OK, but don't present it this way. Please [edit] your question and present it as an entirely new issue. Make sure all essential info is included here. Remove that link. Layout code and text better. You need to make your train of thought *easy to follow* and *concise* if you want people to take the trouble to investigate.

Comment: No, I'm facing same problem right now...that's why I put it here